# Why does ASP.NET Core redirection not work even if I call UseHttpsRedirection?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, https, azure-ad-b2c, http-redirect

I have a web application which uses ASP.NET Core 3.1 on an Azure AppService, combined with Azure AD B2C authentication.
In my Startup.cs code, I call UseHttpsRedirection, but when I visit the site with an empty browser cache / or a new incognito session, using the HTTP protocol, I don't get redirected to HTTPS. Because of this, the B2C authentication doesn't work, so my app is not working.

- [This (HTTP) link is not working.](http://app.relivego.com/nfc-edit)
- [This link (HTTPS) does work.](https://app.relivego.com/nfc-edit)

What is strange though, once you visited the HTTPS site, and then the HTTP one, you will see the redirection **is** working.

What are getting served here are static HTML and JS files, served by the ASP.NET Core self-hosted server (running on a Linux AppService).

What do I miss here? Do I need to make an additional setting in Azure or in my code? Or do I need another record in the DNS?

Comment: The both links redirect to HTTPS for me.

Comment: @abdusco Sorry, it was solved in the meantime. A colleague of mine forgot to set the "HTTPS only" flag in Azure. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that you have to go to the Protocol settings of the App Service and set "HTTPS only" to "on".